# Users can Upload video on single Youtube Channel with or without authentication

Tags: php, zend-framework, oauth, youtube, gdata

I am making a program that will upload video to my youtube channel by any user. But it generates error. My code is as follows:-

```
   require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';
   Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_YouTube');
   Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');
   Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_App_Exception');

   Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

   $authenticationURL= 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin';

   $client = "";

    $email = 'theprofessional1992@gmail.com';

  $passwd = '*******************';

   try {

     $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($email, $passwd, 'cl');

   } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_CaptchaRequiredException $cre) {

echo 'URL of CAPTCHA image: ' . $cre->getCaptchaUrl() . "\n";
echo 'Token ID: ' . $cre->getCaptchaToken() . "\n";

 } catch (Zend_Gdata_App_AuthException $ae) {

echo 'Problem authenticating: ' . $ae->exception() . "\n";

}
```

> Error :-  Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   C:\wamp\www\Yt\zdata\demos\Zend\Gdata\YouTubeVideoApp\Zend\Gdata\ClientLogin.php
>   on line 150

Even i don't know how this functionality will be made.

Please any help ?

Comment: I am working on following :-

Comment: $httpClient = 
   Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient(
               $username = 'theprofessional1992@gmail.com',
               $password = 'everythingisplankrishan108',
               $service = 'youtube',
               $client = null,
               $source = 'MySource', // a short string identifying your application
               $loginToken = null,
               $loginCaptcha = null,
              $authenticationURL);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of
>   March 4, 2014

With YouTube Data API (v3) you can not upload using username and password.
If you want to upload a video to youtube, you have to use these libs:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client 
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/php 
https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/php/resumable_upload.php 
Of course if you don't want authentication each upload process you can use refresh token.

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setClientId($OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID);
$client->setClientSecret($OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET);
$client->setScopes('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/token');
$client->setAccessType('offline');
```

An refresh token will be include in api response. Save it into the database. Remember that you only can get the refresh token at the first time. if you lose it you will have to revoke your application https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1

Now with refresh token you can get access token anytime automatically:

```
$client->refreshToken($refreshToken);
$accessToken = $client->getAccessToken();
```

Comment: Okay i got it. But how it will upload to a single predefined channel. As far as i know it will upload to the authorized user channel.

Comment: you will be asked for select channel when authorize the application.

Comment: i searched a lot but couldn't find any method to select channel.

Comment: It seems you have not yet tried. Each token corresponds to a channel.