# Youtube API javascript upload video to predefined channel

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, google-authentication

I wanted to ask you if I could implement javascript youtube API in order to upload videos to a single predefined channel, without the need of authenticating.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/youtube/5ArDDi1zV9Y), it might not be possible if you are trying to get the server to authorize on your behalf say if you were allowing people to upload videos to a single shared channel. You'd need to do some way of authorizing the client locally on the server which then has the server authorized to the YouTube account.

However, you may refer with this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31397827/5832311) which stated that  if you don't want authentication for each upload process, you can use [refresh token](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_oauth2#OAuth2_Refreshing_a_Token).